# How can this Parallel LC circuit act as a filter?

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, resonance, passive-filter

[image: RLC circuit as a parallel band-pass filter in shunt across the line]

How can the network that is shown in the image in any way alter the voltage being supplied to the output?
i.e no matter what the response of the LC system, the input voltage is **directly** transferred to the output load resistance **R** since it is connected in **parallel** to the input. How can the network then be a **band-pass filter** ? I've referred numerous articles on analysis of parallel RLC networks but none have answered this simple question.Please help!

Comment: You're right, it does not work when you apply a **voltage** at the input. But what would happen if the signal was a **current** ?

Comment: Or that 'voltage' source had an impedance

Comment: True! Its completely understandable in case of an input current source but most of the practical circuits use voltage input signals right? Am I to conclude that this circuit is useless for voltage signals?

Comment: A fair bit of the time there is an implicit assumption that the source has 50\$\Omega\$ impedance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a resonance circuit. It may be simpler to ignore the input voltage.

This filter network will have to be in terms of current because they share the same voltage nodes.

The output voltage will be the current divided by the conductance.

\$V_{out} = \frac{i}{Y}\ = \frac{i}{G + j\omega C + \frac{1}{j\omega L}} \$

\$ V_{out} = \frac{i}{G + j\omega C(1 - \frac{1}{\omega^2 LC})} \$

When  \$ 1 - \frac{1}{\omega^2 LC} = 0 \rightarrow \omega^2 = \frac{1}{LC}\$

This gives a resonance curve looking something like [image: Borrowed from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Universal_Resonance_Curve.svg]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Universal_Resonance_Curve.svg

with the peak at when \$ \omega^2 = \frac{1}{LC}\ \$which is a value of \$ \frac{i}{G} \$ at the resonant frequency.

The bandwidth is measured between the half power points. These are the two 3dB lower than the peak. RLC circuits have a very narrow bandwidth.

The -3dB amplitude will be \$10^{\frac{(20log(\frac{i}{G}) - 3)}{20}}\$ which will eventually too \$ \frac{i}{G} \frac{1}{10^{\frac{3}{20}}}  \$ which is very close too \$ \frac{i}{G} \frac{1}{\sqrt2}  \$.

If you follow the same logic, but with a series RLC circuit, then you will come across a nearly identical derivation. In this case we use impedance instead of admittance and are measuring the output voltage across \$R_L \$ for a corresponding input voltage.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an RF filter, seeing as any proper RF source will have a 50 ohm impedance (or 75 if it's for CATV), the filter forms a kind of voltage divider. The source *can be* a voltage, provided that the filter sees an impedance that isn't zero (and really, once you're in the RF realm, the whole concept of an ideal voltage source gets a bit pointless, at RF, *everything* has an impedance).

At low frequencies, the inductor acts a low impedance, dragging down the voltage (and increasing the voltage drop across the source impedance), while at higher frequencies, the capacitor acts as the low impedance and drags down the  output.

However, the interesting stuff happens when you get close to the resonant frequency of the LC filter. See, parallel resonant circuits have very high tank impedances ('tank impedance' meaning the impedance of the whole filter and not its individual components). So at or close to the filters resonant (or 'center') frequency, it has a high impedance and consequently has little effect on the output. That would make this a "Band Pass" filter, blocking (well, just attenuating really) any and all frequencies that are far away from its center frequency.

Comment: Okay! So this circuit practically works, although ideally it is meant only for current source inputs. Thank you!

Comment: No, it's usually meant for sources with a non-zero output impedance, though the maths (and intuition) does get simpler for current sources. We always use 50ohms (or other impedances in that ballpark) for RF signals (for certain reasonable definitions of 'always').